# Unreal Engine 5.3.1 Not Displaying UI Parameters

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am brand new to UE5 and I've been messing with blueprints following tutorials and stuff, then I compiled the blueprint and it crashed. Afterwards any time I tried opening any project the blueprints would not show details. I'll post a picture to make it clearer. It's been like this for days and I can't find any solution online. It's killing me...

I tried to verify UE5 files, I reinstalled it completely too. I made brand new projects or tried opening old ones and nothing worked. How can I fix this bug?

[https://postimg.cc/t1NtgfhS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXCZD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It's something to do with files being in your /AppData/Local/UnrealEngine
Once I deleted the folder and restarted my UE5 it fixed it. Still have no clue what caused this bug -- but I hope it helps others if they encounter this bug.